# Jquery Anchor Tag Doesnt open a poup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to do 2 things:

1. Open a popup when someone clicks on Lease today (Please note I do not have control over the HTML, so Jquery is the only way to change the HREF)
2. Change the Anchor tag back to "/floor-plans.aspx" after the first click

Somehow the code is not calling the function at all and not sure how to do #2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Change HREF Attribute of Anchor Tag </title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="http://"]').each(function(){ 
            var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
            var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("/floor-plans.aspx", "openPopup()"); // Create new url
            $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
        });
    });
 function openPopup(){
alert("popupopened");
  }
  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/floor-plans.aspx" role="button" class="btn header-button header-cta header-cta-1"><span>Lease Today</span></a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you verified that your selector `a[href^="http://"]` is correct?

Comment: You might also benefit from using a [`.on("click")` event handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this, the first click to do the alert, then the second to NOT do the alert but allow the click (and turn off this handler, first time only we alert)

In addition, I added a class to make the selector much simpler to use/understand.

You did not ask how to tell what was clicked in the function, so I show that as well as how to pass some extra values/objects.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Change HREF Attribute of Anchor Tag </title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="/floor-plans.aspx" role="button" class="btn header-button header-cta header-cta-1 replacer-clicker"><span>Lease Today</span></a>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function openPopup(event,passed) {
      console.log(passed.foo.Name);
      alert("popupopened was "+$(event.target).text());
    }
    $(function() {
      $('a.replacer-clicker').on('click', function(event) {
        // Get prior url if we had it
        let prior = $(this).data('prior-href');
        if (!prior) {
          // do not go there and stop other event handlers from seeing it
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();
          // save old, no prior click
          $(this).data('prior-href', $(this).attr("href"));
          // all it with this instead so we know context of it
          openPopup.apply(this, [event,{foo:{Name:"fooby"}}]);
          // simple
          //openPopup();
        } else {
          console.log(prior);
          //second click (had prior)
          // now turn this handler off
          $(this).off('click');
          // now re-trigger the click, pass some arguments
          $(this).trigger('click',[{foo:{Name:"fooby"}}]);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is hwo you select the anchor and the second one is related on how you use href attribute.

Fixed code:

```js
function openPopup(){
alert("popupopened");
}
$('a[href^="/floor-plans.aspx"]').each(function(){
    var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
    var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("/floor-plans.aspx", "javascript:openPopup();"); // Create new url
    $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="/floor-plans.aspx" role="button" class="btn header-button header-cta header-cta-1"><span>Lease Today</span></a>
```

The correct way is:

```js
$('a[href^="/floor-plans.aspx"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("popupopened");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="/floor-plans.aspx" role="button" class="btn header-button header-cta header-cta-1"><span>Lease Today</span></a>
```

Instead, if the html element is not yet ready you can delegate the click event:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="/floor-plans.aspx"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("popupopened");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <a href="/floor-plans.aspx" role="button" class="btn header-button header-cta header-cta-1"><span>Lease Today</span></a>
```

Comment: The function works but the popup doesn't show alert?

Comment: What does it happen if you change alert with console.log("hhhh")?